# Adding color for a span inside a Link component doesn't change the color of the span?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Sidebar = () => (
  <div style={{ width: '164px', padding: '20px 0px' }}>
    <Menu
      style={{ width: '164px' }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
      defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
      mode="inline"
    >
      <Menu.Item key="1">
        <Icon type="home" />
        <Link to='/'><span style={{ color: 'rgb(199, 143, 95)' }}>Home</span></Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">
        <Icon type="tags" />
        <Link to='/tags'><span style={{ color: 'rgb(199, 143, 95)' }}>Tags</span></Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="3">
        <Icon type="team" />
        <Link to='/users'><span style={{ color: 'rgb(199, 143, 95)', backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>Users</span></Link>
      </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  </div>
);

export default Sidebar;
```

I used antd as a ui framework. Since Link component hides the texts in the span elements i want to change the color of span elements but adding color prop doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Please show code and what you tried to do and explain your problem more in details

Comment: did you remove the basic css assigned to an anchor component ("a") because it probably overrides it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but if you want to have the write "Tags" (which is also a link) written in red, you might try one these two ways:

- `<Link to='/tags'><span style={{ color: 'red !important' }}>Tags</span></Link>`
  This way, you are saying that your CSS rules should override already existing ones. Though, you should try to avoid using the `!important` keyword, unless extreme cases;
- `<Link to='/tags' class='myLink'><span>Tags</span></Link>` This way, first you give a class to the link you want in red, then you need to write some a CSS rule:

  ```
  a.myLink:link, a.myLink:visited, a.myLink:hover, a.myLink:active {
      color: red;
  }
  ```

  Of course, whit this rule you will the red link anytime (if you click it, if you are hover it,..) You can customize that by dividing the CSS rules.